# How to set up a productive and flexible Linux cluster?

Tags: linux, networking, cluster, clustering

I have 7 old computers that are a few years old. I want to cluster them together to create a linux cluster that will run general purpose software(not cluster specific). Is there any software that can distribute the workload of the main computer on all of the other computers through a cluster? I already have a gigabit ethernet switch and enough CAT5 cables to network them together. Any help/tips are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apologies for the somewhat meta question/feature request.  Ideally, there would be a `watch` button next to a given question.  Clicking this would, say, cause an email to be sent to me if someone posted an answer.

If there is another way, please clue me in.  Thanks.